# PhpStorm file structure opens collapsed (MAC)

Tags: macos, phpstorm, file-structure

When you press command + F12 in a class, you normally see all members in an unfolded tree. Now, this consistently opens folded. I updated to the latest major today and later on I noticed this issue. I already tried 'invalidate caches / restart'.

How can I make PhpStorm open this pop up with the tree unfolded like it used to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot -- it's a regression.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38965 -- will be fixed for next version (2017.3.1).

---

**P.S.** No need to ask here and file a bug report to PhpStorm's Issue Tracker [at the same time](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39007) -- If you are so confident that it's a bug .. then why asking here?

Comment: Tnx, I posted here too for more info and a workaround. I haven't used the bug tracking tools of Jetbrains much and I haven't found the info you linked, otherwise I probably wouldn't have.